# Ubuntu 19.04 - VMWare kernel modules updater

Tags: vmware, 19.04, linux-headers

I ran this command:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and it returns the output

> linux-headers-5.0.0-13-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Then I ran the following command to update the linux headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Still, it gets stuck (VMware Kernel Module Updater) at the Compiling/Virtual Machine Monitor.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I fixed it like this.
Downloaded this link:
https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/w15.0.4-k5.0.tar.gz

Extracted the files.

Then ran these commands from terminal of the folder:

1. `tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only`
2. `tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only`
3. `sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/`

Comment: As step 4 I ran 'sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all' and that fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Also works for other vmware versions! Just follow the "Quick guide" steps at: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/blob/master/INSTALL and afterwords modprobe vmmon, modprobe vmnet

Comment: Also I had to reboot after, or it says /dev/vmnet0 is missing.

Comment: @JimboAlba You sir, are a legend.

Comment: I just want to add that there's 471 releases for different versions of VMWare Workstation - I had to find the one that best fit my version and install it, as the one I had been using with a direct link stopped working after an update.  Here's the list: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/releases

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'm running Pop!_OS 19.04. Fixed my VMWare this morning.
I'm running workstation 15.04. I used the vmware-host-modules package over at https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.

When you get there, click on the master branch, and change it to the VMware product that you have. Then follow the instructions in the INSTALL file.

When it is done, restart and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

For version 14, the link is just below :

https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tree/workstation-14.1.1

Compress also `vmmon-only` and `vmnet-only`