# VMware Workstation not running after performing an update on Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: vmware, bug-reporting

After performing a kernel update through Software Updater, VMWare Workstation showing me this and not starting up. I tried reinstalling but that did not work.

[image: VM updater]

[image: VM updater list]

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you send the .log file ?

Answer (score 0):

Here exactly the same problem: 
This solution works to me 
[Ubuntu 19.04 - VMWare kernel modules updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135343/ubuntu-19-04-vmware-kernel-modules-updater)